# Can't remove button border after click, and it's color does not change

Tags: html, css

I have virtually zero experience with HTML and CSS, and I'm trying to create a simple website.
I have buttons from Bootstrap, what I'm trying to achieve is, when a button is pressed, it's text would change it's color and will have no border.
This is what I tried:

```
.btn-secondary:active, .btn-secondary:focus { 
    color: aquamarine;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

But that does not work.
This is the result:
[image]

The change in color does work, but I just can't remove this grey border. I tried looking in Bootstrap docs, but couldn't find anything.
Tried few different things too (such as outline-style etc.) but still, it remains the same.

Comment: Can you use any JS? It would be simpler to use JS for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try `border` style like below code -

```
.btn-secondary:active, .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary:hover { 
    color: aquamarine;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: border has nothing to do with the outline.

Comment: But in OP's question, he just wants to remove the border. @nitnjain

Comment: OP's trying `outline` to remove the border, but the wrong value.

Comment: Yes OP's trying outline property to remove the border So I corrected him to use `border` property instead of `outline`. Also, I visited the bootstrap docs they use the `border` style to wrap their buttons. @nitnjain

Comment: `border` would be useless if OP is using `outline` to produce a border, looks like it from OP's code.

Comment: Your point is correct but here OP's not using `outline` to produce the border, he just wants to remove the already existing style from the button and that is not generated by `outline`. @nitnjain

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: CSS supports focus pseudoclass but it's not supported in all browsers. In couple of years when :focus is more supported pure CSS solutions are great but in this time and place I would highly recommend to use JS.

EDIT part 2: changed let to var.

EDIT part 3: Added support for multiple buttons.

This code includes some JS.

```
<style>
  button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .buttonClicked {
    border: 0;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var clickedButtons = [];
  function onButtonClick(buttonsId) {
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonsId);
    if (clickedButtons.includes(buttonsId)) {
      button.className = '';
      clickedButtons.splice(clickedButtons.indexOf(buttonsId), 1);
    } else {
      button.className = 'buttonClicked';
      clickedButtons.push(buttonsId);
    }
  }
</script>

<button id="button1" onclick="onButtonClick('button1')">
  Button 1
</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="onButtonClick('button2')">
  Button 2
</button>
<button id="button3" onclick="onButtonClick('button3')">
  Button 3
</button>
<button id="button4" onclick="onButtonClick('button4')">
  Button 4
</button>
```

Comment: You can simply remove border with CSS only, no need of JS here.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within

Of course you can. But you shouldn't.

Comment: He can use `hover` instead of `focus` that I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But it doesn't solve anything due the need of checking the click :D If :hover is fine your answer is correct and if not your answer doesn't work in all browsers. I'm not trying to give my answer more credit but been fighting with this kind of problems about five years of my life and some people still use browsers like IE everyday.

Comment: Your opinion is right if CSS doesn't work for all browsers, then definitely you need to write some JS to achieve the solution.

Comment: Added support for multiple buttons. Everytime user clicks a button buttons id is pushed in to array. Before class change function checks if id is in array and if it is removes custom class and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.btn-secondary:active, .btn-secondary:focus { 
    color: aquamarine;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```